# 433M modules w. soldered 34.6cm antenna, first test

Tags: arduino-nano, library, rf

I'm doing a first tx/rx on a pair of modules, and some hams have alluded that they 'autoadjust' - since I've soldered halfwave antennas onto the modules, what's the optimal range for first tests? And will I benefit from 1/2 or 1/4 wave radials? I was thinking about 4-6 spokes from a bicycle wheel. Also, what library would be best for RC control of a medium power pump - I'm pretty sure it's going to induce noise. How far away from the pump should I position the rx module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the antenna should be slightly shorter as the module already has a very small antenna/coil on the  pcb. Just create a sketch that light an led if it successfully received data. Then keep moving further away till you can just barely receive data.  Then try clipping a (few) millimeters or the antenna and see if you can move further away. PS what specific model do you have?

Comment: Good idea, though I will start at ~25m and decrease distance. I trust the deep ham-fu. How much should I decrease it by? And what material would you use to make the antenna (solid core copper wire) completely straight? (and thanks )

Comment: @Gerben It's a noname module. They're all pretty similar, will use 5V for tx, and 3V3 for rx module. Tx works ok, will try it at 25m first.

Comment: Straight wire antennas are the easiest to make. Just power it by a battery, and start walking. `They're all pretty similar`, that's not really useful.

Comment: An english description here: https://arduinotech.dk/shop/rf-data-modul-433mhz/

Comment: I just read 3V3 is the optimal voltage for both tx and rx - bogus?

Comment: For the TX, the higher the voltage the greater the output power, and thus range (in most cases).